# Props shorthand in Reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, svelte, shorthand

In Svelte we can use shorthand when attribute and its value have the same name. E.g.:

```
<img src={src} alt="">
```

is the same as:

```
<img {src} alt="">
```

My question is whether there is a possibility to do the same in React.js? E.g.:

```
<button {type}>Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do it. But you can use `spread operator` to pass the list props.

```
const props = {src, type};

<button {...props}>Click me!</button>
```